# Javascript get id of parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following structure:

```
<div id="accord1_1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
 <div class="panel-body">
   <div id="Dashboard">
    <div id="DashboardFlow">
     <div class="dashboard-caps">
      <div class="dashboard-info">
          <a class="save" onclick="return saveChanges();" href="#">Save</a>
```

When clicking on Save button i would like to get the parent div that is like `accord%_1`. I'll explain myself better:

I have like 30 structures like the one i've shown created. All of them are exactly the same except from the `id="accordX_1"` key which is `id="accord1_1"` in the first collapsable panel, `id="accord2_1"` in the second and so on.

What i need to do is get that id's value.

How can this be done?

Regards,

Comment: Use a proper event handler, and `$(this).closest('.panel-collapse').prop('id')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) and the [startsWith](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector

```
$('.save').click(function(){
 var targetId = $(this).closest('div[id^=accord]')[0].id;
});
```

This will find the first matching parent element in the list of parent elements for the element with class=save, access the matched native element with [0], and the native `.id` property.

Answer (score 1):

Just find the `closest` div on clicking `save`

```
$("a.save").click(function(){

    var curr = $(this).closest("div.panel-collapse[id^=accord]") // Is the div you want;
    var id = curr.attr("id");

});
```